# page redirect with .htaccess [custom URLs]

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

I want to make a referral system, but it's based on a referral system to find the value it had in the database, and I want to redirect the user's page with this code. I tried to explain the structure of the link should be at the bottom. How do we do this?

> DATABASE --> USERCODE(A6465S) --> example.com/A6465S(USERCODE) --> USER PAGE(REDIRECT) --> site.com/users.php?id=10 --> COMPLETED

Comment: Do you mean example.com/123  redirects **to** example.com/user.php?id=123

Comment: For stuff like that I use AltoRouter - you can find it easily.

Comment: How do you get from `A6465S` to `10`?

Comment: @Starkeen I want to do as you say :) Please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your root/htaccess file :

```
#turn on the engine for rewriting
RewriteEngine On

#if the request  is for a existing file or directory, then skip the rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Rewrite the short url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /users.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You're perfect. Thank you very much man.You are best. You are a number. [Sorry I'm using google translate.]